# Bi-directional angular input parameter and eliminating nulls

Tags: angular, typescript

My requirement is simple but had to put some thoughts into it. I have to create an empty array even though it is coming as null from parent component. I have an input element that expects an array[] from parent. The parent sometimes sends `null` instead of empty array that causes the problem. My code is below:

```js
/* child component */
@Input() selectedIds: GenericID[];
```

```html
<!--Parent HTML-->
<sample-listbox 
  id="dataIds" 
  [(selectedIds)]="dataIds" 
  inputType="number">
</sample-listbox>
```

I have made some changes in the child component to alter the input data but the new data is not reflecting in the parent component. I used `set` and `get` keywords but it acts like unidirectional. 
NOTE: I cannot alter the data coming from the parent component.

```js
/* Edited Child component */

 selectedIds: GenericID[];
 @Input('selectedIds')
    set selectedIdss(value: GenericID[]) {
        if (value) {
           this.selectedIds = value;
        }else {
           this.selectedIds = [];
        }
    }
    get selectedIdss() {
        return this.selectedIds;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bi-directional data flow between parent and child is no longer a thing in Angular 2.

You can use an `@Output()` property to emit an event from your child component to the parent when something changes and keep them in sync (see the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)).

Comment: IS there any other way to do this like bi-directional binding?

Comment: You could use a service to keep things synchronized. This is often the case when there's no direct relationship between two components that need to communicate. Up to you.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve editing the parent component.